# Node.js: Execute command on Web Page button click

Tags: node.js

How can I execute a linux shell command on webpage button click or keyboard keypress with NodeJs and PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand well. Do you want to click on a button and that nodejs executes a command? If yes, this is the nodejs part

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls", puts); // Command
```

on the button you'll assign an ajax call onclick that makes a request to nodejs.

Source: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs